# what is the efficient way to check if these conditions apply and perform a set of tasks?

Tags: javascript, performance, switch-statement, set

So I have a javascript object with key, value pairs as such...

```
var listOfQuestions = {
    questionId: question1
    questionId: question2
    questionId: question3
}
for (var i = 0; i < listOfQuestions.length; i++){
    if (questionId == 'someValue1') {
        performTask1;
    }
    ...
    else if (questionId == 'someValue10') {
        performTask10;
    }
    else if (questionId == 'someValue11' || 'someValue12' || ... 'someValueN') {
        performThisSameTask;
    }
```

I know I could change it to a switch case statements and have a more better looking and better performing piece of code. Or I could have create a set of these questionId's and check if the set contains the questionId and perform the task based on that. What's the time complexity of using a set in this case? Is it better to use switch-case or set or any other data structure? Any insight is really appreciated.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed as there is no correct answer and will just solicit personal opinions.

Comment: Please turn your pseudo pseudocode ( objects with a `.length` and duplicate properties? ) into "real" pseudocode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends whether you will use `switch` or `if`, but the more important here is code readability.

If I got correctly your pseudocode I'd go with something like this:

```
// Your questions - list of question object.
const questions = [
    {
        id: 'someValue1',
        question: "First Question ?"
    },
    {
        id: 'someValue10',
        question: "Tenth Question ?"
    },
    {
        id: 'someValue12',
        question: "Twelfth Question ?"
    },
    {
        id: 'someValue22',
        question: "Twenty two Question ?"
    }
];

// Your tasks object.
const task = {
    first: () => {
        console.log("First task performed");
    },
    tenth: () => {
        console.log("Tenth task performed");
    },
    nth: () => {
        console.log("Nth task performed");
    },
    custom_group_task: () => {
        console.log("Custom task performed");
    },
    custom_group_task2: () => {
        console.log('Custom task2 performed');
    },
    default_one: () => {
        console.log("Default task performed");
    }

};

const getGroupTask = id => {
    // Define groups
    const group1 = ['someValue11', 'someValue12'];
    const group2 = ['someValue21', 'someValue22'];

    if(group1.includes(id)) {

        return task.custom_group_task;
    }

    else if(group2.includes(id)) {

        return task.custom_group_task2;
    }

    return false;
};

// Create task
const taskFactory = id => {

    const groupTask = getGroupTask(id);

    if(groupTask !== false) {
        return groupTask;
    }

    switch(id) {
        case 'someValue1':
            return task.first;
        case 'someValue10':
            return task.tenth;
        case 'someValue11':
        case 'someValue12':
            return task.nth;
        default:
            return task.default_one;
    }
};

// Your index
questions.forEach(e => {
    const taskResult = taskFactory(e.id)();
});
```

Simply just organize this in files with well defined tasks and questions and import them.

Comment: ok so I get what you are trying to do and it makes sense to me. But I am confused as to how do I go about having the same exact task to be performed for multiple cases? I necessarily don't want to repeat saying (case 15: doThisTask, case 16: doThisTask, case 300: doThisTask). Sorry for the bad pseudocode again.

Comment: Well, we can do workaround with adding group task function and inject it into `taskFactory`. Edited the code

Comment: thanks. This solutions is perfect. The performance is much better than bunch of if/else statements that I had. Learned a new creative way to work with JS Objects.